# Detecting system locale(language) in html

Tags: html, localization, internationalization

I have a web site working in English. I want to localize the code such that the html text (currently hardcoded in english) can be changed according to system language.

For example:

```
<section id="myInfo" data-bind="with: My.ViewModel.Testing">
    <header>
        <h1>Test Case 1</h1>
    </header>
....
</section>
```

The text "Test Case 1" needs to change to the system specific language. Any hints on how I could achieve that?

Comment: you want to auto-translate your text into all languages? there is no HTML setup for that. thats why chrome asks you if u want to translate, because there needs to be some internal plugin the browser uses to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to detect system locale in HTML. Besides, what would you do with the information? There are no tools in HTML for changing text content.

In JavaScript, there are ways to access the system locale in *some* sense. But this is still wrong approach to localization. Localization should be performed when the page is generated, possibly in response to a user request that specifiess the preferred language.

Answer (score 0):

Figured that one of the ways to achieve this is using the resx files to replace the text and use fmt namespace from html code: